# difference between google api and google rest api?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have gone through this [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)

but dont get exactly the answer what is difference between Google Drive Api and Google Drive Rest Api

Comment: `REST API` is an API, implemented with REST approach. That is the difference.

Comment: @VladMatvienko perfect

Comment: @VladMatvienko thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming when you say Google Drive API you mean the Google Drive Android API.This is a native Android API which utilises the Google Play Services to communicate.

Whereas the rest API is a HTTP API - Which can be used in any platform - Web, Android, iOS.

The Android API is an abstraction layer with certain optimisations. So your choice of API would depend on your use case.